Anaconda blocked across entire organization. Looking for suitable or better replacement to Anaconda
Hello all: As title suggests, my company is > 200 employees. Therefore, according to new Anaconda TOS, there is a $50USD/machine applied if default conda channels are used. However, my company has taken decision to eliminate the use of Anaconda platform and its services completely across the entire company. Even the website is blocked and I cannot access the documentation/help files.
Question: What alternate Python distributions would you guys suggest that can replace Anaconda?
Features that I like(d) in Anaconda: Creating new environments that can automatically manage package dependencies.

For creating python environments that handle package dependencys take a look into poetry.
